# Cast a single database record to Dataset for embeded SSRS report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I'm trying to embed a local SSRS report into my MVC razor page for the very first time. I created a simple report to prove my concept, an .rdlc file. The report has a couple text boxes, logo and a couple tables.

With no tables and no datasets, I can get the report to run in the MVC view without issue. When I add the first dataset, the trouble begins as I cannot seem to come up with the correct way to pass data from my controller to the report.

Part of my problem, it seems ReportDataSource prefers an `IEnumerable` such as a list. In order to display a name and address at the top of the report, I don't need a list of objects, just one object, or a single database row. How can I pass this object as a datasource / dataset?

Here is my current controller code:

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"Reports\AnnualFeeStatement_DRAFT.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", UserDAL.getMember("Simons", "12345", "1988")));

ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

return View();
```

Comment: You can either make a list containing one object, or pass in the values you want to display as report parameters instead of a data source.

Comment: I'll still need to figure out how to correctly pass multiple rows of data for other parts of the form.  I wanted to get the simplest part working first.